# Transient api Caches confused

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, cache, transient

This code works for page 1

```
<?php
            $paged1 = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $recent1 = get_transient( 'recent1' );
                                if ( false === $recent1) {
    $recent1 = new WP_Query ('cat=3&posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged1);
    set_transient('recent1', $recent1, 60*60);
    }
    // do normal loop stuff
    if ($recent1->have_posts()) : while ($recent1->have_posts()) : $recent1->the_post();
    ?>
    <div id="line"><a href="<?php the_permalink () ?>" rel="bookmark">
 <h2><?php the_title (); ?></h2>
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100), array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
 <?php the_advanced_excerpt(); ?>
```

But there is a problem with pagination. Page 1 confused with page 2 or page 3 and etc. On page/2 there is content of page/1 or on the contrary. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This code works" - but it doesn't!

If you're gonna cache paginated posts, you'll need to store them chunked:

```
if ( ! $my_paged = absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) )
    $my_paged = 1;

if ( ! $my_query = get_transient( "recent_$paged" ) ) {
    $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=3&posts_per_page=5&paged=$my_paged" );
    set_transient( "recent_$paged", $my_query, 60 * 60 );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Is it right ?<?php
if ( ! $my_paged = absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) )
    $my_paged = 1;

if ( ! $my_query = get_transient( "recent_$paged" ) ) {
    $my_query = new WP_Query( "cat=3&posts_per_page=5&paged=$my_paged" );
    set_transient( "recent_$paged", $my_query, 60 * 60 );
}
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
<h2><?php the_title (); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

Comment: Why, does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with pagination because you do not take pagination into consideration while storing and retrieving your transient. Give this a try:

```
// Find out which page this is. If 'page' is not a number, set page to 1.
$page = ( ctype_digit( $_REQUEST['page'] ) ) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;

$paged1 = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$recent1 = get_transient( 'recent'.$page );

if ( false === $recent1) {
    $recent1 = new WP_Query ('cat=3&posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged1);
    set_transient('recent'.$page, $recent1, 60*60);
}
```

Also, if you're not aware of it already, look up on "WP Super Cache".

Edit: TheDeadMedic beat me to it.